# Javascript string match specific regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match specific string from this variable.

```
var string = '150-50-30-20=50+skip50-20-10-5=15+1*2*3*4=24+50-50*30*20=0+skip2*4*8=64';
```

Here is my regex :

```
var string = '150-50-30-20=50+skip50-20-10-5=15+1*2*3*4=24+50-50*30*20=0+skip2*4*8=64';

var match_data = [];

match_data = string.match(/[0-9]+(?:((\s*\-\s*|\s*\*\s*)[0-9]+)*)\s*\=\s*[0-9]+(?:(\s*\+\s*[0-9]+(?:((\s*\-\s*|\s*\*\s*)[0-9]+)*)\s*=\s*[0-9]+)*)/g);

console.log(match_data);
```

The output will show

```
[
   0: "150-50-30-20=50"
   1: "50-20-10-5=15+1*2*3*4=24+50-50*30*20=0"
   2: "2*4*8=64"
]
```

The result that I want to match from `string` variable is only

```
 [
     0: "150-50-30-20=50"
     1: "1*2*3*4=24"
     2: "50-50*30*20=0"
 ]
```

Comment: You may use `/(\+skip)?(\d+(?:\s*[-*]\s*\d+)*\s*=\s*\d+)/gi` and whenever Group 1 is not undefined, skip/omit that match, else, grab Group 2 value. See [this **JS demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/mgtqhvp8/2/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is that an answer?

Comment: With ECMAScript 2018 compliant environments, you may use `match_data = string.match(/(?<!\+skip)\d+(?:\s*[-*]\s*\d+)*\s*=\s*\d+/gi)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox No idea, probably it is an answer. I am just not sure about the actual requirement. If something works, it is not necessarily the answer.

Comment: Can you explain your output please?

Comment: I got what you meant.. but i will try it first. @WiktorStribiżew. and for negative lookbehind that you answered on second comment, it will not support on any browser except chrome.

Comment: @WillyantoHalim That is why the second comment starts with *With ECMAScript 2018 compliant environments*... Please confirm you want to exract all sums that are not preceded with `+skip`. Do you only want to support `-` and `*`  or all operations? Maybe relace `[-*]` with `[-*\/+]`, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i know, so that i won't choose the second comment.. i just want to exclude +skip only but with dynamically code. so that in any condition, it could be run.

Comment: So,  https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/mgtqhvp8/2/ is what you need

Comment: okay.. just put yours on answer section.. i will mark it as true answer if i have done checking.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `((?:\+|^)skip)?` capturing group before `(\d+(?:\s*[-*\/+]\s*\d+)*\s*=\s*\d+)` in the pattern, find each match, and whenever Group 1 is not undefined, skip (or omit) that match, else, grab Group 2 value.

```js
var string = '150-50-30-20=50+skip50-20-10-5=15+1*2*3*4=24+50-50*30*20=0+skip2*4*8=64', 
 reg = /((?:^|\+)skip)?(\d+(?:\s*[-*\/+]\s*\d+)*\s*=\s*\d+)/gi,
 match_data = [], 
 m;
while(m=reg.exec(string)) {
   if (!m[1]) {
      match_data.push(m[2]);
   }
}
console.log(match_data);
```

Note that I added `/` and `+` operators (`[-*\/+]`) to the pattern.

**Regex details**

- `((?:^|\+)skip)?` - Group 1 (optional): 1 or 0 occurrences of `+skip` or `skip` at the start of a string
- `(\d+(?:\s*[-*\/+]\s*\d+)*\s*=\s*\d+)` - Group 2:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\s*[-*\/+]\s*\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

    - `\s*[-*\/+]\s*` - `-`, `*`, `/`, `+` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
    - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\s*=\s*` - `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Comment: when i moved `skip50-20-10-5=15` and the string will become `var string = 'skip50-20-10-5=15+1*2*3*4=24+150-50-30-20=50+50-50*30*20=0+skip2*4*8=64';` it didn't work

Comment: @WillyantoHalim Easy fix, use `reg = /((?:^|\+)skip)?(\d+(?:\s*[-*\/+]\s*\d+)*\s*=\s*\d+)/gi`

Answer (score 2):

As per your input string and the expected results in array, you can just split your string with `+` and then filter out strings starting with `skip` and get your intended matches in your array.

```js
const s = '150-50-30-20=50+skip50-20-10-5=15+1*2*3*4=24+50-50*30*20=0+skip2*4*8=64'
console.log(s.split(/\+/).filter(x => !x.startsWith("skip")))
```

There are other similar approaches using regex that I can suggest, but the approach mentioned above using split seems simple and good enough.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var t = string.split('+skip');
var tt= t[1].split('+');
var r = [t[0],tt[1],tt[2]]
```

```js
var string = '150-50-30-20=50+skip50-20-10-5=15+1*2*3*4=24+50-50*30*20=0+skip2*4*8=64';

var t = string.split('+skip');
var tt= t[1].split('+');
var r = [t[0],tt[1],tt[2]]

console.log(r)
```

Comment: this answer is only for 1 situation.. i want the code will run dynamically in any condition.

Comment: @WillyantoHalim you not desciribe desired output - describe it and give more examples in question

Comment: as you saw this post was about regex.. so i want to exclude it from regex.

Comment: @WillyantoHalim so you don't know what do you want on output? - regexp descibe wrong result so it is not  good source of information what do you want

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string = '150-50-30-20=50+skip50-20-10-5=15+1*2*3*4=24+50-50*30*20=0+skip2*4*8=64';
const stepOne = string.replace(/skip[^=]*=\d+./g, "")
const stepTwo = stepOne.replace(/\+$/, "")
const result = stepTwo.split("+")
console.log(result)
```